# What is "Print to File" and can it be used from command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome, printing

When you select "Print to File" in a Gnome print dialog (not cups-pdf):

[image: print-to-file]

... what is the actual command that gets executed? (I'm interested in the postscript variant, as on the image)

On the other hand - maybe there isn't a command call; maybe it is `gtk_print_operation_set_export_filename` from [The new Gtk+ Printing API](http://people.gnome.org/~alexl/presentations/guadec2006-printing.pdf)?

In any case - is there a way for me to utilize this particular code from the command line (not `pdf2ps` and the like)? Say, by using `lpr` to "print to file" to a postscript file - as if I was using the dialog above?

Comment: AFAIK, this is a feature of the subsystem used by some GNOME and GTK+ applications to print stuff (some of these use Cairo). `lpr` interacts with `cups` directly, the print to file option completely bypasses the printing server. it probably doesn't call a command, it just invokes the cairo renderering function in a different way so it generates pdf, postscript or svg output to a file.

Comment: Ah, so its the cairo backend there! Any ideas if a comparable command line is available, that can invoke this rendering function in the same way as the print dialog does? Many thanks for the comment, @njsg - cheers!

Comment: There may be some cairo command line tool (I really don't know), but I guess it's a bit tricky, as many applications use cairo to print their own documents, and that application is the one which is able to *understand* the file format. Cairo won't be able to read random file formats. The closest you can get is to check if the program with the dialog has some commandline option to print a file without opening the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @njsg - the above screenshot was taken from the `evince` print dialog; unfortunately, I cannot see any command line switches by `evince` that would do something like this.. Cheers!

Comment: This is just an UI convention, each program can in principle do what they wish when "Print to file" is selected.

Comment: It's called [`GtkPrintUnixDialog`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPrintUnixDialog.html). If you want to implement your own tool that launches that dialog here's an example in [`pygobject`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/demos/gtk-demo/demos/printing.py?id=3.13.3). I'm posting this as a comment because as far as I know there is no command that does what you want (so there's no answer to your question). The print dialog runs a `GtkPrintJob` (see documentation) which may use a `cairo`+`postscript` backend to get the surface and print the document.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `cups-pdf` package as a solution independent from gnome. After installing the package, add the PDF printer using the cups webinterface at `http://localhost:631` as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#PDF_virtual_printer) ('*General' as printer manufacturer, CUPS-PDF as driver*).

For your convenience, change the output directory with the option `Out` in `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf` to, like, `${HOME}` or whatever you want. Then do as suggested by @[Noam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61634/30431) to print to file.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, the required `apt` package is `printer-driver-cups-pdf`. It sets up a printer called "PDF". Then `lpr -P PDF file_to_print` works. The default location for files is `${HOME}/PDF`.

Answer (score 4):

Print-to-file sends the document not to the printer but to a pdf document.

Same can be done with the cups printing system, which your applications use when they send print commands.

Use the cupsfilter tool. It effectively converts a document. It converts to pdf by default.

```
$ cupsfilter inputfilename > outputfilename.pdf
```

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/774496/297529).

Answer (score 3):

```
lpr -P "Print_to_PDF" file_to_print
```

To get the list of currently configured printers, run `lpstat -p -d`.

Comment: mmm, -P "Print_to_PDF" gives me this error "lpr: The printer or class does not exist."

Comment: See also the [CUPS documentation](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html) for different options of `lp` and `lpr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *lp* printing command to print a file to the default (or only) printer on the system:

```
lp filename
```

or to a specific printer

```
lp -d printer filename
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is late to the party like me it seems the following does the trick at reproducing "print to file"

```
pdftocairo input.pdf output.pdf -pdf
```

I discovered this by opening a pdf with Evince in Gnome and then printing to file. It seems cairo graphics is used in the background when printing to a file this way: running pdfinfo on the resulting file reveals

```
Producer: cairo 1.16.0 (https://cairographics.org)
```