# Printing two pages per sheet from the command line

Tags: pdf, cups, evince, pdftk, lp

Say I start off from a PDF document, say of 12 pages, viewed with **evince**. 
To produce another PDF of 6 sheets, with a page setup of two pages per side, 
I normally use the "Print to File" device listed in the ^P dialogue window.
This works out pretty neatly.

I would like to translate this operation for the command line.

- To my understanding, this is not an operation that **pdftk** can do. Please cross check.
- The  command `lp`, which would accept the option `-o number-up=2`, does not recognize any device called "Print to File", which indeed does not show up in `lpstat -p -d`.
- I am aware of the post [What is “Print to File” and can it be used from command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-is-print-to-file-and-can-it-be-used-from-command-line). I have installed **cups-pdf** whereby a new printer named PDF is acknowledged. However, the print quality of a simple text file is way too raw (for example, no print margins to start with). Moreover, if I reprint an existing PDF file on this device, say `lp -p PDF existing.pdf`, evince can't even manage to open that copycatted output, while this is not the case with the "Print to File" way.
- I had a look at `man evince`. At the bottom, it touches upon a few print preview options and redirects to a [GNOME-developer project page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-print-preview-command). Admittedly I am not able to make sense and use of it.

Is there actually a way to combine the flexibility of the command line with the print quality that I obtain from that "Print to File" option in the GUI  evince?

My test case, again, would be to create from the command line a PDF out of a source document printed with two pages per sheet.

Thanks for thinking along.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is the `pdfnup` (or `pdfjam`) command line tool. You can install it from the repositories of your distribution (`sudo apt-get install pdfjam` for Debian-based distributions, `yaourt -S pdfnup` on Arch etc).

The default options will take the input PDF file and produce an output PDF with two input pages per page:

```
pdfnup -o output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: This produces the desired result ahead of engaging with printing commands.  Man pages are available on-line from [Linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup)

Comment: For `pdfjam` you need to add the option `--nup 2x1`, otherwise it just pipes the document as-is.

Comment: Note that the pdfnup script from pdfjam is no more, you'll have to use pdfjam directly.

Comment: pdfjam sources: https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam and https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam-extras (pdfnup, pdfpun, pdfjoin, pdf90, pdf180, pdf270, pdfflip, pdfbook, pdfjam-pocketmod, pdfjam-slides3up, pdfjam-slides6up), pdfjam old source: [warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam](https://web.archive.org/web/20190918145150/https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam)

Answer (score 7):

To expand on [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254309/205892):

Using `pdfjam` you will need to pass the landscape option as well.
The usage is:

```
pdfjam input.pdf -o output.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape
```

Note that the extra `--angle 90` might save your day, depending on the orientation of the pages in the original PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can print multiple pages:

```
command | lpr -P <printername> -p <priority from 1 to 100>
```

Example of use:

```
ls -l | lpr -P hpprinter -p 2
```

Comment: Hi. This answer bumps against the limitation that, if I launch `lpr -P PDF -p 2` the quality of the result is way too raw. It is useful if that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [this extended answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675108/341485) for non-Americans using ISO A4:

```
pdfjam input.pdf -o output.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape --paper a4paper
```

Otherwise pdfjam seems to default to US-Letter (at least on my machine).