# Print two half-sized copies of a two-sided document at once

Tags: pdf, printing, image-manipulation, lp

I have a two-sided, us-letter format document that I'd like to print two copies at once, by resizing it to half letter (a.k.a. [statement, or organizer L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#Half_letter)).

My current workflow is very inconvenient:

- The original document is two-sided, A, B, C, etc.
- Using PDFSam's [mix-pdf](https://pdfsam.org/mix-pdf/), duplicate each page (so that the document is A, A, B, B, C, C, …),
- Using pdfjam, resize the document and have two pages by page (so that I have A A on the same page, on landscape mode, one of top of the other, etc.),
- Print using `lp -o sides=two-sided-long-edge`.

I am sure there is a simpler way to achieve this, but couldn't find it. An additional hurdle of my current way of doing is that pdfjam introduces extra margin, that I have to remove using `trim`.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is using `pdftk` to double up the pages, which you can then pair using `pdfjam`:

```
pdftk Lorem.pdf cat 1 1 2 2 output - |
    pdfjam --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile Lorem_2up.pdf
```

You can use `/dev/stdout` instead of `Lorem_2up.pdf` to pipe the result to *stdout* for further processing (or printing).

If you want to generalise the solution you need to identify the number of pages and then generate an appropriate double-up command:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
pages=$(pdftk "$file" dump_data | awk '/NumberOfPages/ {print $2}')

cats=()
for ((page=1; page<=pages; page++))
do
    cats+=($page $page)
done

pdftk "$file" cat "${cats[@]}" output - |
    pdfjam --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile "${file%.pdf}_2up.pdf"
```

Reference

- [Printing two pages per sheet from the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254308/100397)

Comment: That's brilliant! I'll try to automate the `cat 1 1 2 2` output to accommodate any size of document and post it as an answer, but your idea of using the `cat` command is precious!

Comment: @Clément if you'd said you'd wanted a generalised solution I'd have written one, but your question stated it was for PDFs of only two pages. I've added a more general solution for you